# Refactoring with generics

Tags: c#, generics

Let's assume, that we have the following classes:

```
class ViewModelA
{
    private ProxyA proxy;

    public ViewModelA(DataA data)
    {
        proxy = new ProxyA(data);
    }

    public void DoSth()
    {
        proxy.DoSth();
    }

    public ProxyA Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            return proxy;
        }
    }
}

class ViewModelB
{
    private ProxyB proxy;

    public ViewModelB(DataB data)
    {
        proxy = new ProxyB(data);
    }

    public void DoSth()
    {
        proxy.DoSth();
    }

    public ProxyB Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            return proxy;
        }
    }
}

...
```

All of these classes are actually a lot longer, but also similar in the same degree.

Is there a (nice) way of converting them all to one generic class? The core problem is the line:

```
proxy = new ProxyA(data);
```

because C# disallows calling parametrized ctors on generic class specializations (in terms of `T`).

Comment: Could you change DoSth to take the data value?

Comment: @PhillipTrelford I can not. `Proxy` object is crucial for this class (and ones, which use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type (and using generics you would), you can call [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create an instance of that type using any constructor you want.

```
proxy = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TProxy), new[]{data});
```

While this will solve your direct problem, you could also think about a design where `ViewModelA` does not know about `DataA` and instead gets passed a `ProxyA`. That would solve all your problems without fancy reflection.

Comment: Passing ProxyA would break encapsulation, because it would extend scope of ProxyA to ViewModel's owner. That would work, but I cannot call it a *nice* solution. The Activator.CreateInstance though looks more promissing (especially, that I construct the ViewModel classes only a few times and that happens only once, so I won't lose too much time on using reflections)

Comment: I've decided to use reflection. These operations are done only a few times, so performance won't suffer and the solution is good enough for me. The other solutions are worth checking though.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by passing in a preconstructed `ProxyA` or `ProxyB` object.

One way of doing it is through inheritance, constructing the object just before calling the base constructor:

```
class ViewModel<TProxy, TData>
{
    private TProxy proxy;

    public ViewModel(TProxy proxy)
    {
        this.proxy = proxy;
    }

    public void DoSth()
    {
        proxy.DoSth();
    }

    public TProxy Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            return proxy;
        }
    }
}

class ViewModelA : ViewModel<ProxyA, DataA>
{
    public ViewModelA(DataA data) : base(new ProxyA(data))
    {
    }
}
```

I've assumed here that `DataA` and `DataB` occurs somewhere in method signatures that you have omitted. If not, you can leave out the `TData` generic type parameter.

Reflection is always an option, but it is best avoided if a solution like this is acceptable. If you want to avoid having to create a new type for a different `TProxy` and `TData`, you could add a second constructor instead:

```
ViewModel(TData data, Func<TData, TProxy> factory) : this(factory(data))
{
}
```

Used as such:

```
new ViewModel<ProxyA, DataA>(new DataA(), data => new ProxyA(data));
```

I'm not sure if that makes sense to do in your application however.

Comment: I can, but: 1. it may not be the only proxy object created inside and I would have to pass all of them to the ctor; 2. It requires extending scope of `Proxy` classes to `ViewModel` owners, which breaks encapsulation (in this case `Proxy` wouldn't be visible to `ViewModel`'s owner because of application logic, but because of implementational details). That will work, but I cannot call it a *nice* solution :)

Comment: +1 for the factory though. This is surely a lot better solution than passing a Proxy inside ViewModel (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, it is not possible to do this with parameterised constructors, without using reflection.  However, one possible variation on this theme:

```
public interface IDataProxy<T>
{
    T Data { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel<TProxy, TData>
    where TProxy : class, new, IDataProxy<TData>
{
    public TProxy Proxy { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel(TData data)
    {
        Proxy = new TProxy { Data = data };
    }
}
```

Comment: That's assuming you can make the proxy implement the interface. Not unreasonable, but sometimes you just can't.

Comment: +1, quite nice solution. The downside is (apart from what @Thorarin said), that for code cleanness I would have to teach Proxy how to work without the Data attached. But maybe it's worth it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSth();
}

class ViewModel<T> where T : IDoSomething
{
    private T proxy;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        proxy = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    //public ViewModel(T data)
    //{
    //    proxy = data;
    //}

    public void DoSth()
    {
        proxy.DoSth();
    }

    public T Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            return proxy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It breaks logic of `ViewModel` class - it is responsible for `DoSth`, not the `Proxy`. Also, If I simply required: `where T : BaseProxy, new()`, I wouldn't have to use reflection - parameterless ctors can be called on generic class specializations.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IProxy
{
    void DoSth();
}

public class ProxyA : IProxy
{
    public ProxyA(DataA dataA)
    {

    }
    public void DoSth()
    { }
}

public class ProxyB : IProxy
{
    public ProxyB(DataB dataA)
    {

    }
    public void DoSth()
    {

    }
}

public class ViewModel<T> where T : IProxy
{
    private readonly IProxy _proxy;
    public ViewModel(T proxy)
    {
        _proxy = proxy;
    }

    public void DoSth()
    {
        _proxy.DoSth();
    }
}

var vm = new ViewModel<ProxyA>(new ProxyA(new DataA()));
vm.DoSth();
```

Comment: It will work, but I cannot consider it a *nice* solution, because you extend visibility of `Proxy` to `ViewModel`'s owner, which breaks encapsulation (the owner shouldn't know anything about `ViewModel`'s locally-related classes).